# For $dX = Adx+Bdy$, how to compute $\frac{\partial x}{\partial X}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Suppose I know

\begin{align}
dX = A dx + B dy
\end{align}
Then I know
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} =A, \quad \frac{\partial X}{\partial y} =B
\end{align}
Then is there any smart way to compute
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial X}, \quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial X}
\end{align}

---

What I know :

Take simple example "two dimensional polar system"
\begin{align}
&x= r\cos(\theta), \quad y = r\sin(\theta) 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  &dx = \cos(\theta) dr - r \sin(\theta) d\theta \\
  &dy = \sin(\theta) dr + r\cos(\theta) d\theta
\end{align} in terms of $dr, d\theta$, by multiplying inverse metric for coefficients,  I have
\begin{align}
  &dx = \cos(\theta) dr - r \sin(\theta) d\theta \\
  &dy = \sin(\theta) dr + r\cos(\theta) d\theta
\end{align}
Then Finally
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = \frac{x}{r}=\cos(\theta), \quad \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} =\cos(\theta) \\
&\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} =\frac{y}{r} =\sin(\theta), 
\quad \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} =\sin(\theta) \\
& \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} =-y = -r\sin(\theta), \quad \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} =-\frac{1}{r} \sin(\theta) \\
& \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} = x = r\cos(\theta), \quad \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{r}
\end{align}
It seems they related somehow but how?

Comment: You know $\left(\tfrac{\partial X}{\partial x}\right)_y=A$, the ${}_y$ subscript denoting what is held constant in the partial derivative's definition, so $\left(\tfrac{\partial x}{\partial X}\right)_y=\tfrac1A$. Is there some other definition of $\tfrac{\partial x}{\partial X}$ you're asking about?

Comment: You might read (and understand) my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982030/using-differentials-not-partial-derivatives-to-prove-that-d-dx-sin-r/3982900#3982900).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\o{\tt1}\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$The
problem is that **single** equation does not provide enough information. The desired calculation requires the **full** system of equations:
$$\eqalign{
dX &= A\,dx + B\,dy \\
dY &= C\,dx + D\,dy \\
}$$
Now calculate the inverse of the coefficient matrix
$$\eqalign{
M &= \m{A&B\\C&D}
\quad\implies M^{-1} &= \m{E&F\\G&H} \implies
\m{dx = E\,dX + F\,dY \\dy = G\,dX + H\,dY} \\
}$$
and extract the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
\p{x}{X} &= E \\
}$$
These [block matrix inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) formulas can be used to express $E$ in terms of $(A,B,C,D)$ by treating them as $(\o\times\o)$ matrices.