# Using Differentials (not partial derivatives) to prove that d/dx = -sin()/r

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, differential

I am trying to prove the parts of each component of the inverse matrix in the attached image. I have tried using differentials and then solving for the other components. (I'd like to solve it this way). Trying to solve for example, $\frac{d\theta}{dx}$ (in the bottom left of the inverse matrix [attached below]) $$x = r cos(\theta)$$ –> $$dx = cos(\theta)dr - rsin(\theta)d\theta$$Then observing that we are holding $r = constant$, thus $dr = 0$. I get that $\frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{- 1}{r sin(\theta)}$, which is close. I put this in a partial calculator and made $\theta$ a function of x and r, $\theta = cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{r}\right) = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}\right)$. Taking the $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$ I get the right answer due to r being a function of x and y. If I use the $cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)$ and take the partial I get what I stated above ($\frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{- 1}{r sin(\theta)}$). Also I tried to replace dr in $dx = cos(\theta)dr - rsin(\theta)d\theta$ by using $r^2=x^2+y^2$ by replacing dr with $rdr = xdx + ydy$ where I assumed dy to be constant. Which yielded me the wrong answer. I'd like to improve my logical thinking so any advice on what I did would be great as well. Thank you!

Summary: I am trying to prove using differentials (not partials) that $\frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{-sin(\theta)}{r}$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note in your arguments, that $r$ is not generally a constant when taking the partial wrt $x$, and likewise neither is $dy$. One very important issues is you're actually taking partial derivatives here, as indicated in the proposed duplicate question, as $\theta$ is actually a function of $x$ and $y$, for example.

Comment: Not exactly as I'd like to use differentials not partials. I did see that one. I did end up substituting the differential part of dr in the above dx = cosodr - rsinodo and simplified it down to the correct thing but I feel like, I still don't grasp using differentials.

Comment: Thank you, I do realize that I am actually taking the partials but in physics we tend to use differentials and I'm new to it and trying to grasp that concept better. Also thank you I am very excited to join such an amazing community!

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: Thank you I will not do this again and will take down the image, very sorry I just joined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot just write $\frac{d\theta}{dx}$. In thermodynamics, there is a notation which really is useful and important. They write partial derivatives with a subscript to indicate what variable(s) are left fixed. So, for example, if we have $z=f(x,y)$ and we want to find the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, fixing $y$, we write $$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_y \quad\text{or}\quad \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y.$$
This is important because we may have lots of variables flying around and it's important to know what variable(s) are fixed.

In your example, we can think of $(x,y)$ as functions of $(r,\theta)$. Then if we write $\partial x/\partial\theta$, this ordinarily signifies $\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}\right)_r$. When you fix $r$, then it becomes true (because we're essentially doing one-dimensional calculus) that
$$\left(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right)_r = \frac 1{\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}\right)_r}.$$
However, you're muddling things by instead trying to compute $\left(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right)_y$, and these are two totally different beasts. You really *must* be careful about keeping track of the independent variables. If you change those, more chain rule comes in.

Just to reiterate, you are trying to compare
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right)_r &= -\frac1{r\sin\theta} = -\frac1y \quad\text{and} \\
\left(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right)_y &= -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} = -\frac{\sin\theta}r.
\end{align*}

By the way, be warned. In general, we do not have
$\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta} = \frac1{\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}}$. Indeed, since $x=r\cos\theta$, we have $\partial x/\partial\theta = -r\sin\theta$ (which is $-y$). On the other hand, since $\theta =\arctan(y/x)$ (at least for $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$), we have $\partial\theta/\partial x = -\frac y{x^2+y^2}$, which is very different from $-y$. This is your $-\sin\theta/r$, of course. The correct relation comes from the complete derivative matrices (called Jacobians), which are inverse $2\times 2$ matrices.

You can do this all correctly with differentials (differential forms, in fact), but you must still keep track of who the independent variables are. And you really *must* stop writing things like $d\theta/dx$ unless $\theta$ really is a function *just* of one variable $x$. To get your first formula, you would have to write $d\theta$ in terms of just $dx$ and $dr$; to get the second you would have to write $d\theta$ in terms of the usual $dx$ and $dy$. It's just a question of what the independent variable**s** are.

Comment: Thank you so very much!! This is very helpful! I am new to this all and the notation! Again thank you so very much!!

Comment: You're very welcome. For future reference, if you're looking for a rigorous but accessible treatment of multivariable calculus and linear algebra, you might check out my YouTube videos, linked in my profile. There's some physics in there from time to time, too. :)

Comment: I will most certainly!! I will subscribe right now!! I love linear Algebra and Multivariable!