# Properties of ordinary derivatives in mutivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I had a question related to the properties of partial derivatives and those are used casually but aren't mentioned explicitly in any books the way those properties are mentioned in case of ordinary derivatives.

1.Is $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ the inverse of $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$? For example if $z=x^2y$ then $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=2xy$. Again,$x=\sqrt{\frac{z}{y}}$,so $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{z}{y}}} \times \frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{2xy}$. So,in this random example the property does seem to be true. I tried for few other examples as well.Or are there any examples where this property fails?

2.Is $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \times \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}$? For example,if $z=\sin(5xy+y)$,then $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ is done as $5y\cos(5xy+y)$. Here,the *CHAIN RULE of ordinary derivatives* has been applied,as it is the same as $\frac{\partial \sin(5xy+y)}{\partial (5xy+y)} \times \frac{\partial (5xy+y)}{\partial x}$. So indeed the chain rule of ordinary derivatives applies here but it is not acknowledged as the chain rule for multivariable calculus as its chain rule is different which is $\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$.

Among all the examples I have encountered so far,the properties of ordinary derivatives seem to fit in partial derivatives. But these aren't mentioned properly in the books so I assumed these to be not true in general. But these properties are used in partial differentiation(the no. $2$ mostly which I mentioned as without the chain rule of ordinary derivatives,there is no other way of partially differentiating $\sin$ or $\cos$ functions). So I want to know if these properties are valid,why aren't they mentioned anywhere. Or are the valid in general?

Comment: You can find this discussed in dozens (or more) posts. As you surmise, these formulas aren’t in books because they’re wrong. The standard example to try is polar coordinates: $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$. Compare $\partial x/\partial r$ and $\partial r/\partial x$. Your example worked because you are fixing $y$ and then it reduces to the single-variable case.

Comment: @TedShifrin how would one go about differentiating $\sin(x^2+2y+3z)$ without using the chain rule of normal derivatives? The answer is $\cos(x^2+2y+3z)\times 2x$. Here the $\cos$ term comes by treating $x^2+2y+3z$ as a single variable$=t$ first and then differentiating $\sin t$ wrt. $t$. If the chain rule of ordinary derivatives doesn't work here,how can one differentiate the mentioned function?

Comment: That is just fine, and it is the single-variable chain rule ($y,z$ are fixed). Try the example I gave in my first comment. [My answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3982900) may help explain things.

Comment: @TedShifrin in polar coordinates,$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ from your example, so $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Again,$x=\sqrt{r^2-y^2}$,hence $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\frac{2r}{2\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}=\frac{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2x}$ and hence they indeed seem to be inverses.

Comment: @TedShifrin your link isn't working unfortunately.

Comment: The link is fixed. You are using the wrong variables. You have to differentiate $x$ as a function of $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: @TedShifrin,could you please share your thoughts on this post? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839660/fixed-variables-in-clairauts-theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the vast majority of questions about partial derivatives, the trouble has to do with our suboptimal notation for them that usually doesn’t indicate what’s being held fixed. To clear things up a bit, I’ll use the notation $\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_y$ to indicate that the variable $y$ is being held fixed while we differentiate $f$ with respect to $x$.

In your first example, you found that $\left.\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right|_y=\left(\left.\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right|_y\right)^{-1}$. This isn’t very suprising – you treated $y$ as a constant (so it might as well have been $2$ or $\pi$ instead), and then this relationship follows directly from the corresponding relationship for ordinary derivatives. Ordinary derivatives are just partial derivatives of univariate functions; partial derivatives are just ordinary derivatives of multivariate functions interpreted as parametrized families of univariate functions.

Somewhat more formally, we could say that we have a bivariate function $z(x,y)$; we consider it as a parametrized family of univariate functions, $z_y(x)=z(x,y)$; we invert those functions to obtain another parametrized family of univariate functions, $x_y(z)$; and then we consider this family as one bivariate function, $x(z,y)=x_y(z)$; so we have

$$
\left.\frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial x}\right|_y:=\frac{\mathrm dz_y(x)}{\mathrm dx}=\left(\frac{\mathrm dx_y(z)}{\mathrm dz}\right)^{-1}=: \left.\frac{\partial x(z,y)}{\partial z}\right|_y\;.
$$

That’s just a roundabout formal way of saying “treat $y$ as a constant”.

The counterexample given by Ted Shifrin concerns a different case. Here we have two bivariate functions, $x(r,\theta)=r\cos\theta$ and $y(r,\theta)=r\sin\theta$, and we invert them *as a whole*, not holding anything fixed, not going through an imaginary stage of univariate functions: $r(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\theta(x,y)=\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$. Here there’s no reason to think there should be any particular relationship between $\left.\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right|_y$ and $\left.\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right|_\theta$. Note that here we have two different variables being held fixed, $y$ and $\theta$, whereas in what you did it was the same variable $y$ being held fixed in both cases.

If we do hold the same variable fixed, we get the same result here as you did: $\left.\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right|_\theta=\cos\theta$ and, with $r=\frac x{\cos\theta}$, $\left.\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right|_\theta=\frac1{\cos\theta}$, and also $\left.\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right|_y=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and, with $x=\sqrt{r^2-y^2}$, $\left.\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right|_y=\frac r{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}x$.

The same applies to what you wrote about the chain rule. Again, you were keeping $y$ fixed in all of what you did, so it might as well have been $2$ or $\pi$, so it’s not surprising that everything works as for univariate functions: $\left.\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right|_y=\left.\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\right|_y\cdot\left.\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}\right|_y$. As a general principle, you can take any result for ordinary derivatives and tack on any number of variables that you hold fixed to obtain a corresponding result for partial derivatives, as long as you use the same set of fixed variables for each derivative.